# Assertion of array in Karate

Tags: karate

I have a response which is an array and the size of this array will keep on changing and I need to assert a particular value for every element in the array. This is how my compressed response would look like:

```
    {
    "kind":"NodeList",
    "apiVersion":"v1",
    "metadata":{
        "resourceVersion":"1234567"
    },
    "items":[
        {
            "status":{
                "conditions":[
                    {
                        "type":"NetworkUnavailable",
                        "status":"False"
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"MemoryPressure",
                        "status":"False"
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"DiskPressure",
                        "status":"False"
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"PIDPressure",
                        "status":"False"
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"Ready",
                        "status":"True"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "status":{
                "conditions":[
                    {
                        "type":"NetworkUnavailable",
                        "status":"False"
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"MemoryPressure",
                        "status":"False"
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"DiskPressure",
                        "status":"False"
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"PIDPressure",
                        "status":"False"
                    },
                    {
                        "type":"Ready",
                        "status":"True"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }   
    ]
}
```

The size of the array items will change so i want to iterate it in loop where i can get assertion like:

```
* assert response.items[0].status.conditions[4].type == 'Ready'
* assert response.items[1].status.conditions[4].type == 'Ready'
* assert response.items[2].status.conditions[4].type == 'Ready'
```

How can this be done in karate because i know i can do this in java using for loop. Can someone pls help with this.

Comment: Can you share the response in proper format?

Comment: @cyrilgeorge153 I have updated the response in proper format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 * match each response.items[*].status.conditions[4].type == 'Ready'
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me as it gives me an array of status ["Ready","Ready,"Ready"] as response and as i mentioned earlier, the size of array changes so i cannot check if how many Ready are there in the response

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you please check now?